# jQuery script that makes ajax call not working on iis

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

This scripts works fine when running from visual studio, but does not work on iis. It does not return data and fails

```
error: function (xhr) {alert('error');}
```

could it be the url format? do I need to add @url

```
<script>
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Register/SearchResults',
        datatype: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { npi: $("#NPI").val(), first: $("#First").val(), last: $("#Last").val() },
        async: true,
        processData: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#SearchResults").empty();
            $("#SearchResults").append('<table class="table" id="records_table"><tr><th></th><th>DEA#</th><th>Life#</th><th>NPI #</th>' +
               '<th>NYS License</th><th>License Type</th><th>First Name</th>' +
               '<th>Last Name</th></tr></table>');

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#records_table").append('<tr id="' + data[i].NPI + '" ><td><input id="chk_' + data[i].NPI + '"  value="' + data[i].NPI + '" name="rbnSR" type="radio"></td><td>' +
                   data[i].DEA + '</td><td>' +
                   data[i].Life_Hosp + '</td><td>' +
                   data[i].NPI + '</td><td>' +
                   data[i].LIC + '</td><td>' +
                   data[i].License_Type + '</td><td>' +
                   data[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' +
                   data[i].LastName + '</td></tr>'
                   )
            }
            $("#btnSubmitBNForm").show();
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}

$("#btnSubmit").click(function (evt) {
    $("#searchFormError").hide();
    if ($("#NPI").val().trim() != "") {
        load();
    }
    else if ($("#First").val().trim() != "" || $("#Last").val().trim() != "") {
        load();
    }
    else {
        $("#searchFormError").show();
    }
});

$("#btnSubmitBNForm").click(function () {
    if ($('input[name="rbnSR"]:checked').length != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Register/BNEForm?id=' + $('input[name="rbnSR"]:checked').val(),
            datatype: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {},
            async: true,
            processData: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "false") {
                    location.href = '@Url.Action("IdProofing", "Register")/' + data;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Plase select a value from table");
    }
});

$("body").on("click", "#records_table tr", function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").prop('checked', false);
    $("#records_table tr").removeClass("success");
    $(this).addClass("success");
    $("#chk_" + $(this).attr("id")).prop('checked', true);
});


</script>
```

Comment: Try using `@Url.Action(..)` for all of your url's.

Comment: What does the xhr actually contain when it errors? If it's a web api endpoint, you might be missing the /api/ before the controller, or it otherwise can't find the route.

Comment: Please check. Format might be wrong    url: '@Url.Action("BNEForm","Register")?id' + $('input[name="rbnSR"]:checked')

Comment: Matti ,     0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'id' is undefined

Comment: ********Works fine in Visual Studio. It is not working when running in IIS*********

Comment: Can you add your server code in for /Register/SearchResults or whatever endpoint isn't working.

Comment: Also, when it's hosted on IIS, does it have an application specific path? Like http://website.com/APP and in visual studio it's http://localhost/ ?

Comment: matti,   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename    is the application path in iis

Comment: @user2224493 what about the url that you enter to browse to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105393/discussion-between-user2224493-and-matti-price).

Answer (score 0):

use @Url.Action(..) in all your urls. It should work in both visual studio and when published to iis